# How to create a Facebook timeline style date scroller?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of the Facebook timeline date selector/page scroller. This can be seen in the top right hand corner of a Facebook timeline page. When you select a year, using an animated affect, the page scrolls down the timeline to that specific year. Here's the code that I've been trying to get to work for me:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("ul a").click(function(event){
              if($(this).hasClass("fourthlink")){
                        // get the coordinates of the fourth div
            var offset = $("#sect4").offset();
                        // alert the y coordinate; I'm getting the right coordinate: 1062 
            alert(offset.top);
                        // Here's where I'm trying to move the page to the right spot
                window.moveTo(offset.left,offset.top);
                        // I've also tired window.scrollTo(offset.left,offset.top);
            }
        })


    });
</script>
```

The first thing I'm trying to do is just get the widow to scroll to the right div. Then, I would like to add an animation affect similar to Facebook's.

Comment: You have to replace: `window.moveTo()` to `window.scrollTo()`.

Comment: You can check this http://www.technotarek.com/timeliner/timeliner.html

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul a").click(function(event){
          if($(this).hasClass("fourthlink")){
                    // get the coordinates of the fourth div
        var offset = $("#sect4").offset();
                    // alert the y coordinate; I'm getting the right coordinate: 1062 
        alert(offset.top);
                    // Here's where I'm trying to move the page to the right spot
            window.scrollTo(offset.left,offset.top);
                    // I've also tired window.scorllTo(offset.left,offset.top);
        }
    })
});
```

You have to replace: `window.moveTo()` to `window.scrollTo()`. Or if that doesn't work, try this:

```
$("html, body").animate({
    top: offset.top,
    left: offset.left
});
```

Comment: I have it commented in my code that I've tried window.scrollTo as well and that does not seem to be working either.

Comment: Okay, in that case, try this. `$("html, body").animate({top: offset.top, left: offset.left});`

Comment: that didn't work either. I just opened up and tried it in another browser just to make sure but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research and using some some different search terms I stumbled upon a [simple plugin](http://djpate.com/2011/01/01/animated-scrollto-effect-jquery-plugin/) that solved my problem, so I thought I would share it.